# How to retrieve only a specific field from child entity on @OneToOne relationship, not all fields?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When I use jpa's `@OneToOne` annotation, I want to get the `userName` field from the table, not all fields. What should I do instead?

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
public class Menu implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4462798713783196961L;

    /**
     * id
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    ...

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "createUserId",referencedColumnName = "userId")
    private User createUser;

   
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createTime;

}
```

What do I need to do, can I get the `userName` field in the `User` object, but not all of it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a POJO with required fields. e.g. You only want `id` from `Menu` and `userName` from `User`:

```
public class CustomMenu {
    private Long menuId;
    private String userName;
    
    public CustomMenu(Long menuId, String userName) {
        this.menuId = menuId;
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    // getters, setters
}
```

Then you can write a query with hql using the constructor in the `CustomMenu` with parameters `new com.yourpackage.CustomMenu(m.id, m.createUser.userName)` and join `User` entity (`join m.createUser`) :

```
TypedQuery<CustomMenu> query = entityManager.createQuery("select new com.yourpackage.CustomMenu(m.id, m.createUser.userName)"
                + "from com.yourpackage.Menu m join m.createUser", CustomMenu.class);
List<CustomMenu> menus = query.getResultList();
```

This generates one sql query with inner join fetching only required fields :

```
select menu0_.id as col_0_0_, user1_.user_name as col_1_0_ from menu menu0_ inner join user user1_ on menu0_.create_user_id=user1_.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution seems good! But, how to do if i haved nested entities so... nested POJO objects in the `CustomMenu` please?