# JPA projections inside entity

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, one-to-one

I am working on an application which has an entity called Post. I also have a User Details entity which is mapped with createdBy column in Post entity. I have modeled their relation using @OneToOne annotation in Post entity.

```
public class Post {
  ... other fields

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name='created_by', referencedColumnName='id')
  public UserDetails createdBy;
}

public class UserDetails {
  public Integer id;
  public String name;
  ... other fields
}
```

When i fetch the Post entity, it is returning the user details entity also with all its fields. But i need to read only id and name from user details. I tried to use Projections to achieve this, but i am not able to use user details projection inside Post entity. Is it possible to use a projection inside an entity and map using @OneToOne?
I am using spring-boot-starter-jpa for my project.

Comment: you can see  this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67055725/how-to-retrieve-only-a-specific-field-from-child-entity-on-onetoone-relationshi

Comment: The solution mentioned in this post requires us to create another pojo and create queries. I have lots of entities which require createdBy field. Creating custom POJOs for all those is not possible. Is there any way to map JPA projections under @OneToOne annotation?